# How change button->load gif->text

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm tring to passs from a button, load an image gif and after a text. This is the code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: link,
    type: "POST",
    data : formData,
    beforeSend: function() {  
        //THIS works
        $('input[id....]').replaceWith("<img src=http://img.ffffound.com/static-data/assets/6/77443320c6509d6b500e288695ee953502ecbd6d_m.gif id=100 /> ");
    },
    success: function(data) {
        if(data!="0"){

            var i=   $('img[id=100]').replaceWith("<p>"+data+"</p>");
            alert(i);

        }else{
        }
    },
    failure: function(result){
        console.log("FAILED");
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

The first step ( pass from buttom to image ) is ok.
The second step (pass to image from text) is not correct because it doesn't work. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Missing `'` in `beforeSend`. Typo or what?  `$('input[id....]')`

Comment: Maybe `data!="0"` is false?

Comment: create a fiddle and show what you want to achieve

Comment: You may want to change `failure: function(){}` to `error: function(){}`

Comment: no It's all correct. the only problem is this line:   var i=   $('img[id=100]').replaceWith("<p>"+data+"</p>"); . It doesn't replace the element

Comment: Do you have an img[id=100]? Check `$img[id=100].length`.

Comment: yes. I think I wrong something!